# NetSuite - SuiteTalk search for a VendorPayment object by external Id ( and get its internal ID)

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

Im trying to get a VendorPayment object internal id by having its external id.
Maybe someone did such a search? the API seems to be very verbose..

help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider adding hyperlinks pointing to the API points you are referring to, and potentially include where *exactly* you are stuck. What have you tried so far? Is there any error message that you cannot get around? The more precise you are, the more likely it is for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the externalId, you don’t need to do a search. You can use the get operation by creating a RecordRef that references the externalId.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to search how to do it with the WebService API and will update.

Answer (score 0):

Making tests about this i get this code, i give to you this example(in PHP) of searching items by internal id maybe helps someone.

```
$item_id                        = new RecordRef();
$item_id->internalId            = $by_item;

$rec                            = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$rec->operator                  = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator::anyOf;
$rec->searchValue               = $item_id;

$itemSearchBasic->internalId    = $rec;
$itemSearchBasic                = new ItemSearchBasic();
$itemSearchBasic->type          = $itemTypeFld;
$itemSearch                     = new ItemSearch();

$itemSearch->basic              = $condition;
$search_field                   = new ItemSearchAdvanced();
$search_field->criteria         = $itemSearch;

$request                        = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord          = $search_field;
```

And then you use your Netsuite Client to execute the search.